# How to catch application/json and text/html requests in Application_BeginRequest

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

How to catch `application/json` and `text/html` requests in `Application_BeginRequest`?`
I' ve tried to iterate `Request.AcceptTypes` but I am not shure if this is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/putting-your-website-in-a-maintanance-mode-based-on-a-weekly-schedule) is what you looking for:

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Maintenance_Mode"] == "on")
{
    Context.RewritePath("Maintenance.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I need Application_BeginRequest to implement a maintenance-mode.